# Deleting "item" whan its picked up/when im standing on it

Tags: java, libgdx

I have this ArrayList that I'm using to generate 2 types of swords that has from 1 to 5 levels. When I "pick it up" I want it to be gone forever. How do I dispose that sword?

[image: How spawned swords look]

This code allocate and generate the Sword(s) Renderer class:

```
private List<Sword> swords = new ArrayList<Sword>();
Then in public Renderer() method I do:

for (int i = 0; i<10 ; i++ ) {
            swords.add(new Sword());
        }
```

When I'm standing on it:

```
if(sword.myLevel<3){
                sword.pickMe();
            }
```

In the `render()` they are displayed on the screen:

```
for (Sword sword : swords) {
    sword.createMe();
}
```

And here is my Sword class:

```
public class Sword {
    private TextureRegion sprite;
    public Vector2 position;
    private int x, y;
    private int size;
    private Random r;
    private boolean pickme = false;
    public int myLevel;
    public Sword() {
        position = new Vector2(x, y);
        r = new Random();
        position.x = (r.nextInt(15))*GameRender.tilesize;
        position.y = (r.nextInt(15))*GameRender.tilesize;
        size = GameRender.tilesize;
        myLevel = r.nextInt(4);
        sprite =getSprite();
        System.out.println(myLevel);
    }
    private TextureRegion getSprite() {
        if(myLevel<3){
            sprite=AssetLoader.s1;
        }else sprite=AssetLoader.s2;
        return sprite;
    } 
    public void pickMe(){
        //GameRender.batch.draw(sprite, 10, 10, size, size);  
        pickme = true;
    }
    public void createMeShape(){
        //GameRender.shapeRenderer.rect(position.x, position.y, size, size);
    }
    public void createMe() { 
        //draws it
        GameRender.batch.draw(sprite, position.x, position.y, size, size);  
        if(pickme){
            //draws that im standing on it
            GameRender.batch.draw(sprite, GameRender.playerx, GameRender.playery-10, size, size);  
        }
        pickme=false;
    }
    public static void Update() {

    }
}
```

Ignoring the whole (`if pickMe()`) in the `createMe()` how do I delete this specific sword when I'm on it?

Comment: In addition [Arraylist in Java Example – How to use arraylist](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/arraylist/arraylist-in-java-example-how-to-use-arraylist/) explain the usage of ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the Sword forever after picking it up, you'll have to remove it from the ArrayList of Swords.

```
if (sword.myLevel<3){
    sword.pickMe();
    swords.remove(sword);
}
```

Comment: it crashes, dont know why

Comment: What is it telling you? If you don't have anything in the list at one point, there's nothing to remove. The problem can also be something else. I recommend reading the ArrayList tutorial that ill feedyou posted as a comment to your question.